# JAVAFX con implementacion css

Tags: java, css, ubuntu, javafx, javafx-css

Tengo este codigo java de javafx

```
public class FormularioGeneral extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {            
        TabPane tabPanel = new TabPane();
        Tab tab = new Tab();
        Tab tab2 = new Tab();
        Scene scene= new Scene (tabPanel, 1000,1000);

        Label usuario= new Label("usuario");
        TextField usuarioT = new TextField();
        Label password = new Label("password");
        PasswordField passwordT = new PasswordField();
        Label sexo = new Label("sexo");
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton r1 = new RadioButton();
        RadioButton r2 = new RadioButton();
        r1.setToggleGroup(group);
        r1.setText("hombre");
        r2.setToggleGroup(group);
        r2.setText("mujer");
        Label hobby = new Label("Hobby");
        ComboBox hobbyCombo = new ComboBox();
        hobbyCombo.getItems().addAll("futbol","baloncesto","escalada","alpinismo","sofing","OTROS...");
        Label descripcion = new Label("Descripcion");
        TextArea areaDescripcion = new TextArea();
        Label formacion = new Label("Formacion");
        CheckBox fp1 = new CheckBox();
        fp1.setText("Fp1");
        CheckBox fp2 = new CheckBox();
        fp2.setText("Fp2");
        Button b1  = new Button();
        b1.setText("ENVIAR");
        b1.setId("boton1");
        Button b2 = new Button();
        b2.setText("CANCELAR");
        b2.setId("boton2");

        HBox otro = new HBox();
        otro.setSpacing(10);
        otro.getChildren().addAll(b1,b2);

        b2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                usuarioT.setText("");
                passwordT.setText("");
                areaDescripcion.setText("");
                fp1.setSelected(false);
                fp2.setSelected(false);
                r1.setSelected(false);
                r2.setSelected(false);
                hobbyCombo.setValue(null);
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);

        root.setPadding(new Insets (10,200,20,100));
        root.getChildren().addAll(usuario,usuarioT,password,passwordT,sexo,r1,r2
                                  ,hobby,hobbyCombo,descripcion,areaDescripcion,
                                  formacion,fp1,fp2,otro);

        tabPanel.getTabs().addAll(tab,tab2);
        tab.setText("Formulario");
        tab2.setText("Formulario vacio ");
        tab.setContent(root);


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        String css = this.getClass().getResource("css.css").toExternalForm();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Y el siguiente codigo CSS

```
#boton1 { 
    -fx-text-fill: red; 
}
```

El problema esta siendo que a la hora de ejecutar me esta dando el siguiente fallo:

> > Exception in Application start method
> >     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> >         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
> >         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> >         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
> >     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
> >         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
> >         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
> >         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> >     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> >         at fxengeneral.FormularioGeneral.start(FormularioGeneral.java:103)
> >         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
> >         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
> >         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
> >         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
> >         at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
> >         at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
> >         at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
> >         ... 1 more
> >     Exception running application fxengeneral.FormularioGeneral
> >     /media/verodaht/2cdb6e9f-d1e4-4a65-a5c7-e79e268bb88e/2DAM/Desarrollo de interfaces/proyectos/FXEnGeneral/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1052: The following error occurred while executing this line:
> >     /media/verodaht/2cdb6e9f-d1e4-4a65-a5c7-e79e268bb88e/2DAM/Desarrollo de interfaces/proyectos/FXEnGeneral/nbproject/build-impl.xml:806: Java returned: 1
> >     BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

El problema me esta dando a la hora de añadir el CSS

Estoy usando netbeans en ubuntu 18

Answer (score 1):

Has agregado un nivel extra de abstracción al llamar al método. La capa "reflection" ajusta cualquier excepción en una excepción tipo "InvocationTargetException", que le permite determinar la diferencia entre una excepción realmente causada por una falla en la llamada de "reflection" (tal vez tu lista de argumentos no era válida, por ejemplo) y una falla en el método llamado.

Simplemente use el método getCause() en la excepción "InvocationTargetException" para retornar la excepción original.

Haz lo siguiente:
Elimina el thwors Exception de tu función para que quede así:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    try{
        ... aquí tu código
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo primero, gracias. Ahora me gustaría saber, donde capturo la excepción ya que no encuentro el sitio donde capturarla.

Comment: De tu función quítale el "throws Exception" para que te quede así: 
"public void start(Stage primaryStage){..." luego dentro escribe try{aquí todo tu código...}catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }. Voy a editar mi respuesta para que se vea mejor...

Comment: Gracias compañero